# how to write to a file via a python script in cron

Tags: python, cron

I tried to write to a file every minute using cron this is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
    a = 'date {!s}'.format(datetime.now())
    print a
    f.write('date {!s} \n'.format(datetime.now()))
    print 'done'
```

then I did

```
chmod +x /tmp/test.py
```

then I added the cron for root

```
sudo crontab -e
```

entry into cron

```
*/1 * * * * /tmp/test.py
```

in postfix I see this every minute, showing that the script is running with no errors

```
 From root@tawanda.robot  Wed Apr 15 22:56:01 2015
Return-Path: <root@tawanda.robot>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@tawanda.robot
Received: by tawanda-lx2 (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 48CA79A13DF; Wed, 15 Apr 2015 22:56:01 +0200 (SAST)
From: root@tawanda.robot (Cron Daemon)
To: root@tawanda.robot
Subject: Cron <root@tawanda-lx2> /tmp/test.py 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20150415205601.48CA79A13DF@lx2>
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 22:56:01 +0200 (SAST)

date 2015-04-15 22:56:01.246885
done
```

but if I open `/tmp/test.txt` it is empty, if i run `test.py` manually it writes to the file as expected

how do I solve this mystery

Comment: Its writing a `test.txt`, but which one? Use an absolute file name instead.

Comment: but why does it work if i run the python script directly

Comment: `open('test.txt', 'a')` opens "test.txt" in the program's current working directory. When you run the script manually, its in the local directory. When its run by `cron`, its in whatever directory *cron* is using as its working dir. That directory depends on how you registered your cron job (user job, system job, etc...) and now cron is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you search `test.txt`? Because you add script as root user `test.txt` should appear in `/root` directory (user home directory).